# .Net 3.5 App Start Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have .net 3.5 app that I built in VS 2008. App works fine on my pc and other pc's i have tried. I have also published on several other production servers.

But my app on a particular server does not work. I have checked permissions, gave them to iisusrs, network service. Tried running process mon. but no luck. Would appreciate if somebody can help me.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Project.Global..cctor() +500
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Product.Global' threw an exception.]    Project.Global..ctor() +0
>   ASP.global_asax..ctor() in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\Project\5b298990\c958346b\App_global.asax.aqngqd-g.0.cs:0
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   fillCache) +146    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +298
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +79
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +10371979
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +258
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +382
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11411878
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4401140

Comment: You know it would *really* help if you included line 500 of the `Project.Global` consructor

Comment: That line is commented. I am not sure what its saying 500. Anyways, I got it fixed. it was a looking for a key in config file that was not there, hence null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static constructor for `Product.Global` is raising a `NullReferenceException`.  This is likely due to some hard coded value that is different or unavailable on that system.

Potential candidates would be localization issues (trying to parse strings in the wrong culture) causing a value to not be initialized, a missing configuration value, or anything else that is occurring within the static initialization of that type.

Comment: yea, I was missing something in in web.config. Thanks for your help.